# How to make CSS changes to H1 on Home Page only without reverting it for the rest of the site?

Tags: css, wordpress

So this works, but it looks awfully wrong to me.

I only want to change the H1 CSS attributes for the main page, but it affects all the pages, so I have to revert it back afterwards. I find it hard to believe this is the proper way of doing it.

Can anyone recommend a cleaner approach?

```
/* Change CSS for H1 on main page hero box */

.helpie-single-page-module .helpie-primary-view .content-area h1 {
    margin-top: -65px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 4px #c69956;
}

/* Undo the above changes for the rest of the site */

.helpie-single-page-module .helpie-primary-view #primary.content-area h1 {
    margin-top: initial;
    margin-bottom: initial;
    font-weight: initial;
    font-family: initial;
    text-shadow: initial;
}
```

I've added this code to the Additional CSS box on Wordpress.

It's for content created by the Helpie KB Wiki Plugin, so I can not find the standard "page-id" like I normally would on a normal Wordpress page.

Thanks.

Comment: according to your code, the only page without #primary.content-area is the homepage. So you can use the :not css pseudo class: .helpie-single-page-module .helpie-primary-view .content-area:not(#primary) h1 {...}

Comment: @ZionAy you should consider filling in the ellipsis there and posting it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, it seems that all the pages have the h1 as a descendant of an element with class "content-area", but only the homepage doesn't have the id "primary" on that element.

If this is the case, you can use the :not CSS pseudo-class to catch only the homepage h1. The :not CSS pseudo-class selects the element only if it doesn't match the given selector.

[Link to explains and examples on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Example with your code:

```
.helpie-single-page-module .helpie-primary-view .content-area:not(#primary) h1 {
  margin-top: -65px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  text-shadow: 3px 2px 4px #c69956;
}
```